# How do I make this reddit widget open it's links up into new tab?

Tags: html, widget, reddit

Here is the Reddit widget code:

I'd like for every clickable link in the reddit widget box to open up into a new tab. 
Any idea of how to do this? Thanks For all your help!

Answer (score 2):

So, for example, reddit generates this for you for a widget code. The problem is that it will open any links in the same window.

`<script src="http://www.reddit.com/r/satire/hot/.embed?limit=5&t=all" type="text/javascript"></script>`

You can make it open in a new tab/window (based on browser settings) by adding **&target=blank** :

`<script src="http://www.reddit.com/r/satire/hot/.embed?limit=5&t=all&style=off&target=blank" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Adding the bolded script seems to do the trick just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the target="_blank" attribute to each link in the widget with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rembeddit a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I really appreciate it. I'm not really sure where I would put that in here though. Do you have an idea? The widget code: <script src="http://www.reddit.com/r/altnewz/hot/.embed?limit=20&t=day" type="text/javascript"></script>